# Linux process - messages from kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have been learning about different IPC mechanisms present in Linux, for communication between user space processes.

I want to ask what are various ways in Linux for the kernel to communicate with the user space process (kind of opposite to system call, where user space initiates request) ? Can signal be one of them ? What are the others ?

Answer (score 2):

A signal is a classic kernel-to-process communication in some cases. Sure, any process with appropriate UID can use `kill()` to send a signal, but signals like `SIGCHLD` or `SIGWINCH` almost always come from the kernel.

Specific to Linux, you can look at the `signalfd()` system call. The usual signal handling is via an "upcall", but `signalfd()` gives a process a different way of receiving signals.

The return value of system calls could be considered a kernel-to-user process communication. This varies a lot, but `fork()` is an example. The parent process gets back a non-zero process ID (or -1 on error) and the child process gets back zero.

The `poll()` and `select()` system calls have arguments where the kernel sets values in the arguments to indicate which file descriptors have which events/state changes available to them. That's more like an "inout" formal argument, but the kernel does set values.

The `inotify` API allows kernel-to-process communication via a `read()` on a special file descriptor.

The POSIX asynchronous I/O system seems to have multiple ways to communicate with a user process, including starting a thread when an I/O occurs, if I read the man page correctly. I've never done POSIX async I/O, and it looks tricky.